# What does さいですか mean?

Tags: meaning

I came upon this conversation:

> A:「あ、あの・・・」
>
> 俺は、そこにいた役場の職員らしき人物にたずねた。
>
> B:「はい、なにか・・・？」
>
> A:「この辺で、サングラスをかけたクールな感じの女性、見かけませんでした？」
>
> B:「さあ・・・？」
>
> A:「さいですか。ども・・・」
>
> B:「・・・・・・」

I went through the fifteen or so words listed in the edict dictionary for さい and only came up with rhinoceros which doesn't seem like a perfect fit.

I swear I've seen the exact same phrase in a manga too somewhere, but never paid attention to it enough to look it up.

It sounds like そうですか to me. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Try a monolingual dictionary next time; It will be far more helpful than the  bilingual sources that are insanely popular among many J-learners.  [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%95%E3%81%84-507095#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) explains it as:

> ［形動{けいどう}］《「さよう」の音変化{おんへんか}》「さよう」のいく分{ぶん}ぞんざいな言{い}い方{かた}。「さいざんす」「さいです」

「さい」 is a slightly rough (or unrefined) way of saying 「さよう/左様」("***indeed***", "***that's right***", etc.)

「さいですか」 is actually pretty close to "***Oh, I see***." in feeling.  Thus, it is also close to 「そうですか」 in meaning.

Comment: Thanks. I do use monolingual dictionaries, but require a starting point of some sort. When you are faced with [six pages of results](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/jn/%E3%81%95%E3%81%84/m1u/), it is kind of intimidating.

Comment: I understood from your Daijisen quote that the word's usage is limited: only used with the copula. Is that correct?

Comment: Weblio has an entry on さいですか [here](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B).